# Refer to a particular UITextField inside a particular UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have `UITableView` that is created programatically, and I have written code to programmatically create a `UITextField` on each and every cell.

When the user taps on the text field, a picker appears and the user can select an item from the picker, and after the selection is made, the selection should be displayed in the text field of that particular cell.

Now the problem that I am facing is, whenever I tap on the text field from any of the table view cells, the picker appears correctly, but the after an item is picked from the picker, the value gets stored in text field of the last table view cell. Why does this happen?

Could someone please explain to me how to refer to a particular text field so that I can perform some action on that particular text field?

Comment: Please post some code. It's easier to understand code than a vague description.

Comment: Where are you assigning the value to the text field? Please post the code you are using to process the selection from the picker.

Answer (score 0):

Create a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, and use it for cells. Add a property to reference its text field:

```
@interface YourTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong) UITextField *textField;

@end
```

Then, assign the text view to the cell when you create it:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";
    YourTableView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = ... // Create the cell here
        UITextField *textField = ... // Create your text field here

        cell.textField = textField; // Assign the text field to the cell
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Once you have done this, your text field is now linked to the cell it is in, so you can get the text view from the cell and set its value.